# A lock has an incorrect combination but since it was originally open it remains open

Tags: java, methods, locking

Where I'm running in to problems is when a lock is already open, then pretty much an incorrect combination won't make a difference because it will remain open. This seemed easy when I read it and tried it, but the test case isn't passing. I marked the bit of code I created that isn't passing with a comment. Can someone help me figure out why it isn't working?

```
public void open(Combination opening){
    Lock temp = new Lock(upper, opening);

    if(opening.equals(unlock)){
         cl = true;

    }else {
    //this if statement is what I came up with to find if it is open 
        if(temp.isOpen() == true){
            cl = true;
        }
        cl = false;

    }
}


public boolean isOpen() {

    boolean op = true;
    if(cl == false){
        op = false;
    }   

    return op;
}


public void close() {

        cl = false;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several stylistic issues here, but I think the problem may lie with your temp Lock

```
if(temp.isOpen() == true){
```

I don't see why you need the temporary lock

```
public void open(Combination opening){

   // If the combination is right open the lock
   // if it was already open no change
   if(opening.equals(unlock)){
     opcl = true;
   } 
   // no else, if combination was wrong 
   // leave the status as it was
}
```

Now as a stylistic issue the way you treat booleans is very bad. Never write

```
if ( bvalue == true )
```

just write

```
if ( bvlaue )
```

That's the whole point of booleans, they **are** true or false.

Hence your check is far more complex than needed, this is all you need.

```
// The  method  isOpen, which   returns a   
// boolean indicating  whether the lock    is  opened  or  not.
public boolean isOpen() {   
    return opcl;
}
```

opcl's job is to hold the state of the lock, it's true or false, so just return that.